How do I create a terminal session from the WSS url that I got from `aws-sdk-ssm` client in Rust?
I want to connect to my ec2 instance using aws ssm sdk for rust. What is the best way to create an interactive terminal session? Here is the following code I am using to create an ssm session:
    pub async fn create_ssh_session(&self, instance_id: &str) -> Result<()> {
        let output = self
            .client
            .start_session()
            .document_name("SSM-SessionManagerRunShell")
            .target(instance_id)
            .send()
            .await?;

            let wss_url = output.stream_url().unwrap();
            let (mut ws_stream, response) = tokio_tungstenite::connect_async(Url::parse(wss_url)?).await?;

            // Print response to confirm successful connection
            println!("Connected: {}", response.status());

        
            let output = self
            .client
            .terminate_session()
            .session_id(output.session_id().unwrap())
            .send()
            .await?;
        // println!("{:#?}", output);
        Ok(())
    }

I have tried to connect using tokio tungstenite to connect to the WSS url but I am not sure if this is the best way.
EDIT: when I try to connect, it gives me status code 101 (switching protocols) what does this mean and after starting session with ssm I receive wss_url and the token. According to the documentation, it says the token is used to authenticate connection with managed node. I want to know how I can do so when creating the stream.

What do you mean by 'best way'? Does this code fail to establish a connect, and if so, what is the connection error?

@user2407038 I want to know, how to properly create and join this session, and how I can create a ssh-like experience. I have updated the question with some more details!

Instead of communicating directly with the ssm agent on the instance, I decided it would be simpler to interact with the session-manager-plugin as  suggested by @john. There is no solid reference that I could find in regards to using session-manager-plugin from the command line and I referred to this question here.
here is the basic workflow on how one can spawn a session using the aws sdk for rust with session-manager-plugin:
pub async fn create_ssh_session(&self, instance_id: &str) -> Result<()> {
        // start session get session_id, token_value and stream_url
        let output = self
            .client
            .start_session()
            .document_name("SSM-SessionManagerRunShell")
            .target(instance_id)
            .send()
            .await?;
        
        // create ssm plugin json message
        let response = ResponseJson {
            SessionId: output.session_id().unwrap().to_string(),
            TokenValue: output.token_value().unwrap().to_string(), // Assuming `token` is defined elsewhere
            StreamUrl: output.stream_url().unwrap().to_string(),
        };

        // commenting code for reference 
        // let template =r#"{"Target" : "{instance_id}","DocumentName": "AWS-StartPortForwardingSession","Parameters" : {"portNumber": [22],"localPortNumber": [3232] }}"#;
        // let ssm_plugin_document = json!(template.replace("{instance_id}", instance_id.into()));
        // let plugin_string = serde_json::to_string(&ssm_plugin_document)?;
        let response_string = serde_json::to_string(&response)?;
        let mut session_manager_plugin = Command::new("session-manager-plugin");
        let run_command_output = session_manager_plugin
            .args([
                response_string,
                "ap-southeast-2".into(),
                "StartSession".into(),
                "https://ssm.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/".into(),
            ])
            .spawn()?;
        let result = run_command_output.wait_with_output()?;

        let output = self
            .client
            .terminate_session()
            .session_id(output.session_id().unwrap())
            .send()
            .await?;
        Ok(())
    }

I am simply spawning session-manager-plugin as a process with the right arguments using the SSM-SessionManagerRunShell document.

(here's the information I've gathered when creating tooling using the ssm-agent start-session api)
As per awscli ssm start-session documentation, it requires the sessionmanager-plugin for your OS.
(NOTE: awscli utilizes the same api's the aws sdk's expose)
DOCS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/start-session.html#description
The sessionmanager-plugin is a collection of golang code that handles the websocket streams and protocol (IE: console, portforwarding, etc)
https://github.com/aws/session-manager-plugin
The above code is not packaged as a golang module, you can use it in your project as a library to produce binaries for your customizations.
